# Difference between (age==18) and (age===18) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

I was doing this program and not getting output but if I entered age 18 after typecasting the age in the second block of code I got the output why is it so?

And if I use only two "==" sign then also I got the output but in case of "===" I didn't get the output.

- `age == 18` Got the output
- `Number(age)===18` Got the output
- `age === 18` Didn't got the output

Both the codes are given below.

With "==="

```
var age=prompt("Enter your age");
if(age<18){
  alert("Sorry, You are too young to drive this car Powering off");
}else if(age>18){
  alert("Powering On Enjoy the ride!");
}else if(age===18){
  alert("Congratulation on your first riding Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

With typecasting "Number(age)===18"

```
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
if (Number(age) < 18) {
  alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (Number(age) > 18) {
  alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (Number(age) === 18) {
  alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: `prompt` returns a string. If you use strict equality then a string is never equal to a numbe: `console.log("18" === 18)`. Instead of casting the value in every test, you can do it once at the beginning: `var age = Number(prompt(...));`.

Comment: Case one and three are identical so I'm not clear what you're asking

Comment: @Liam: I think the first case is a typo it really is `age == 18`.

Comment: @Liam: In the first case there is "==" instead of "===" Sorry! my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#notes) always returns a value in string format.

Suppose a string and number have same value (say 18 and '18'). Here the value is same, only the type differs. Comparing a string value with a number will return `true` if only value is compared and `false` if type is also compared.

`==` compares two value without comparing the types. `==` is called as **Abstract Equality Comparison** which compares value only, not type. `==` will perform a type conversion when comparing two things.

```js
console.log(18 == '18'); // Expect true
```

`===` compares two value by comparing the types. `===` is called as **Strict Equality Comparison** this will compare both value and type

```js
console.log(18 === '18'); // Expect false
```

In case of `Number(age) === 18`, the string age is converted to numeric age and hence this both the value is od type number. Hence this will return `true`

[Read More on `==` and `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

```js
const age = prompt("Enter your age");
console.log(`Type of Age = ${typeof age}`);
const numbericAge = +age; // String to number conversion, Same as Number(age)
console.log(`Type of Numeric Age = ${typeof numbericAge}`);
if (numbericAge < 18) {
  alert("Sorry, You are too young to drive this car Powering off");
} else if (numbericAge > 18) {
  alert("Powering On Enjoy the ride!");
} else if (numbericAge === 18) {
  alert("Congratulation on your first riding Enjoy the ride!");
}
```